# How to debug strongly named assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, strongname

I used to avoid the strong name validation by `sn` tool. This is how I did:

Use `sn -tp xxx.snk` to get the token, then I added the token to registry at these two paths manually, they are `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification`, and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName\Verification\`.

This did work for my application and I can debug in my local environment.

But when I use this in our new application, which is a version got upgraded from the old one, it's not working. When I start the application, this popup window just shows up.

[image]

And I actually don't know what's updated, maybe some new features added. I'm trying to fix some bugs in the new version.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

I tried with many ways avoiding the strong name validation searched online. But didn't work.

Following are the links I found about this issue:

[How to: Disable the Strong-Name Bypass Feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc713694(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/keithmg/archive/2012/03/20/strong-name-validation-failed-exception-from-hresult-0x8013141a.aspx)

Comment: I've edited your title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/130208/158100) where the consensus is "no, they should not".